# Joining two tables to see the effect of an event over a time span

Tags: sql

I have a warnings table of with entries indicating when warning messages were sent telling users they need to pay:

```
     Date  user
========= =======
 1/2/2018    123
 2/4/2018    123
3/15/2018    124
4/17/2018    125
etc.
```

Then I have a records table that generally records when a user has made a payment.

```
     Date    user  amount  country
========= =======  ======  =====
 2/1/2018   123     50     UK
 3/1/2018   123     150    UK
 4/1/2018   125     300    US
 5/1/2018   124     100    CAN
etc.
```

I'd like to know what the difference in average payments 2 days before the warning and 2 days after the warning per country.

Comment: And what is your question? If you want to know the payments difference, I suggest you either look at the data and calculate by yourself or you write a query.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a `join` and aggregation.  This will use standard SQL syntax for the date manipulations.  The syntax in your database might vary:

```
select u.country,
       avg(case when p.date < w.date then p.amount end),
       avg(case when p.date >= w.date then p.amount end)
from warnings w join
     payments p
     on p.user = w.user and
        p.date >= w.date - interval '2 day' and
        p.date <= w.date + interval '2 day'
group by u.country;
```

To be honest, I think the total would be more interesting than the average.